# XCUIApplication().textFields["hiddenTextField"].typeText("input") on UITextField with CGRectZero Frame

Tags: objective-c, xctest

My iOS app has a non visible UITextField I use to capture user input and then display it in my own UI.

```
UITextField *hiddenTextField;
hiddenTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
hiddenTextField.accessibilityIdentifier = @"hiddenTextField";
[hiddenTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(hiddenTextFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
hiddenTextField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:hiddenTextField];

[hiddenTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

It works as expected. I am trying to write automated tests in Swift which include input to this field.

```
XCUIApplication().textFields["hiddenTextField"].typeText("input")
```

Because the view has a CGRectZero Frame the automation fails with response:

> No matches found for Find: Descendants matching type TextField from input

Has anyone run into this before and what strategies have you used to interact with the UI from the tests? Thanks.

Comment: This is quite an unorthodox UI setup. Why don't you want the user to be able to see what they are typing into the text field?

Comment: Users can still see there input. It is just mapped to a UILabel so we can have more control over how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500968-typetext) on Apple's site, as long as the keyboard is active, you can use the `typeText` method on any element that is an ancestor of the focused responder:

> The element or a descendant must have keyboard focus; otherwise an error is raised.

Given the above, you should be able to simply type on the application using the following:

```
XCUIApplication().typeText("input")
```